# What are some good books on the Italian game, including the Evans Gambit and Two Knights Defense family of openings?

Tags: opening, books, italian-game, two-knights, evans-gambit

It's been about 10 years since I played tournament chess regularly. My last rating was 1586 USCF, but it had been as high as 1717.

I recently decided to get back into playing chess, and am looking for some recommendations for a book or two on those openings as white. I've pretty much always played e4, starting the Giucco in high school and later the Bishop's opening/KGD, based on Soltis' Winning with e4. I'd prefer to be able to buy them on Amazon or the USCF site.

I would also be willing to buy a dvd or software that covers these openings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I looked for a similar book, the best I could find is [this somewhat dated work by Jan Pinski](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/185744373X).

[This newer book by Glenn Flear](https://www.everymanchess.com/starting-out-open-games) apparently contains 88 pages about the italian, Evan's gambit and two knights.

If you have played the Bishop's opening before maybe [this is the book for you](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857446178): It advocates going into the Italian game by 2.Bc4.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know there's a book that covers all of those openings well. The Pinski book tries to but I don't think they do a good job.

My favorite book on the Evans is Harding's book.

The two knights can go in a lot of different directions so you might look into how you want to play it first.

The Giuoco Piano and modern bishop's opening may look similar but are very different. I don't know of any book that gives good coverage of both.